# mortgage monthly payment with delayed first payment python

Tags: python, numpy, finance

There are many ways to compute the mortgage monthly payment, this can be done using `numpy-financial` package as follow:

with an interest rate of 4.84, and an amount of 5000 over 60 months duration

```
import numpy_financial as npf
npf.pmt(4.84/100/12, 12*5, 5000)
```

-93.99009193143375

with simple code

```
interest_rate = 4.84 / 100 / 12
loan_duration_months = 60
amount_credit = 5000
 monthly_payment = amount_credit * (interest_rate * (1 + interest_rate) ** loan_duration_months) / ((1 + interest_rate) ** loan_duration_months - 1)
print(monthly_payment)
```

93.99

I need to adapt the code to take into consideration the first payment is delayed n months (e.g: 6 months)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the mentioned problem is simple

First we need to compute the amount of interest of our loan that adds up to the loan amount, let's say we borrowed 10000$ with an interest rate of 5%, the accumulated interest of our loan over 6 months (meaning we didn't make a payment during this 6 months)

```
interest_rate = 4.84 / 100 / 12
loan_duration_months = 60
payment_delayed_months = 6
loan_amount = 10000

delayed_period_interest_amount = interest_rate * (payment_delayed_months - 1) * loan_amount
print(delayed_period_interest_amount)
```

201.66666666666666

Now we can compute monthly payment as if we have an initial loan amount 10201.66, using one of the previous mentioned in the problem, for example

```
import numpy_financial as npf
npf.pmt(4.84/100/12, 12*5, 10201.66)
```